# Oracle SQL Developer not able to detect services in oracle wallet

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, wallet

We are using Oracle wallet to connect to Cloud database which works fine for one instance. We also have on-prem database where the wallet was provided by the customer and when I select the wallet the service names are not detected. Does that show that there is an issue with the cwallet.sso & ewallet.p12 files provided by the customer. We are using 19.2 SQL Developer.

Comment: The wallet does NOT contain service names. When you download the connection details, it's a zip file that contains the wallet, AND the connection info (tnsnames.ora, ....).

Comment: the service names are IN that tnsnames.ora file in the Zip...make sure that tns file is intact

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, yes we had the tnanames.ora file in the zip file but the problem was the wallet files were within a folder hence sql developer was not able to read the entries. Thanks agin.